# Как вывести все данные из БД

Tags: php, laravel

Мне надо вывести все статьи, а не по одиночке. Может быть можно чем-то заменить функцию `find`?

```
public function aboutus() {
  $about_s1 = Abouts::find('1');

  return view('frontend.aboutus')->with('about_s1', $about_s1);
}
```

Представление:

```
<div class="col-md-12 py-5 text-left">
  <h1>{{ $about_s1->title  }}</h1>
  <h5>{{ $about_s1->subtitle}}</h5>
  <p>{{ $about_s1->description }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function aboutus() {
$about_s1 = Abouts::get(); 
return view('frontend.aboutus')
    ->with('about_s1', $about_s1);
}
@foreach ($about_s1 as $item)
<div class="col-md-12 py-5 text-left">
<h1>{{ $item->title  }}</h1>
<h5>{{ $item->subtitle}}</h5>
<p>{{ $item->description }}</p>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Рекомендую при оформлении вопроса отделять логику от представления (поправил ваш вопрос).
2. Необходимо подготавливать данные для отправки в поток вывода.
3. Просто открываем [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#creating-views) и пишем (в контроллере):

```
public function aboutus() {
  return view('frontend.aboutus', ['articles' => Abouts::all()]);
}
```

4. В представлении (например, `blade`):

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
  <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
  <h5>{{ $article->subtitle }}</h5>
  <p>{{ $article->description }}</p>
@endforeach
```

5. Метод `find()` может принимать как идентификатор модели, так и массив идентификаторов. Смотреть [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models). Передавать строку - сильно:)